# Substract two fields of two consecutive rows in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file as follows:

```
5 6
7 8
12 15
```

Using awk, how can I find the distance between the second column of one line with the first column of the next line. In this case, distance between 6 and 7 and 8 and 12 and print as follows, distance of first line set to zero:

```
5 6 0
7 8 1
12 15 4
```

Comment: show us the code you are having trouble with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'NR==1{ $3=0 }NR>1{ $3=$1-p }{ p=$2 }1' file
```

The output:

```
5 6 0
7 8 1
12 15 4
```

---

- `p=$2` - capture the 2nd field value (`p` - considered as *previous* line value)

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
awk 'NR==1{val=$2;print $0,"0";next} {print $0,$1-val;val=$2}' Input_file
```

Adding explanation now too successfully.
Checking for NR==1(when first line of Input_file) is there, then create a variable named val tp second field of the Input_file and then print the current line with "0" then do next(which will skip all further statements). Then printing the current line along with $1-val's value and then assigning the value of variable of val to $2 of the current line then.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print $0, (NR>1?$1-p:0); p=$2}' file
```

Comment: There is `awk '{$0=$0FS(p?$1-p:0);p=$2}1' file` but brevity's not a desirable attribute of software where conciseness is.